# Three.VideoTexture stretches portrait video

Tags: three.js

I am using Three.VideoTexture(video) to load video on canvas. It's work perfectly fine with landscape videos. But when i tried to load a portrait video, on canvas video gets stretched.

```
var wrap3D = $("#" + threeJsPreviewHTMLElement);//.find(".wrap3d");

    videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var WIDTH = 520, HEIGHT = 520;

    var domID = "videoContext";
    if (!isDesktop) {
        HEIGHT = $("#modalTumbler3d").height();
        WIDTH = $("#modalTumbler3d").width();
        domID = "videoContextDevice";
    }

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    if (!wrap3D.find('#' + domID).length) {
        wrap3D.append(renderer.domElement);
    }
    else {
        wrap3D.find('#' + domID).replaceWith(renderer.domElement);
    }
    renderer.domElement.id = domID;

    //Two CAMERA options - perspective is preferred
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, WIDTH / HEIGHT, .1, 20000);       
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 150);
    scene.add(camera);

    //Lights
    var hemLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x999999, 0xffffff, 1);
    scene.add(hemLight);
    var spotLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x555555);
    spotLight.position.set(0, 15, -20);
    scene.add(spotLight);
    var spotLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x555555);
    spotLight.position.set(0, -15, 20);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    //size and position of tumbler from camera
    var Y = 0;
    var A = 0;
    var B = 0;
    var scale = 1;

    //cylinder for the movie preview
    //var movieFrame = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 1.8, 2.5, 50, 1, true, -1.59, Math.PI)
    var movieFrame = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 2.5, 100, 3, true, -1.59, Math.PI)


    //var movieFrame = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 1.9, 2.5, 50, 1, true, -1.59, Math.PI)
    var movieMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: videoTexture, overdraw: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

    var moviePlayer = new THREE.Mesh(movieFrame, movieMaterial);
    moviePlayer.position.y = Y;
    moviePlayer.rotation.y = A;
    moviePlayer.renderOrder = 14;
    moviePlayer.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
    scene.add(moviePlayer);

    //control with the mouse or two finger pinch
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
    controls.maxPolarAngle = 2.5; // radians
    controls.minDistance = 5;
    controls.maxDistance = 10;
    controls.enabled = false;
```

This is what i have tried to play video. I have used CylinderGeometry to load video in Cylinder form.

Comment: Can you please show your code? Or provide a live example via jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: @Mugen87 added code

Comment: Please include how you define the 3D object which uses the video texture.

Comment: @TheJim01 please have a look, added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the texture will simply cover the whole CylinderGeometry. So any distortion you see is result of the aspect-ratio of the video not matching the aspect-ratio of the cylinder-fragment..

Based on your code you have there a height of 2.5 and a width of Math.PI, so your aspect-ratio is ~1.25. Now for a portrait-video (aspect-ratio <1) you need to adjust the geometry. (so for a 3:4 potrait-video you'd need a thetaLength of `1.875/radius` instead of Math.PI).